# get_previous_post in same categories

Tags: next, previous

I have a post in two categories, 1 and 2.

I want to get the previous post in the two categories, 1 **and** 2.

```
get_previous_post(true);
```

With that code I'm getting the previous post in category 1 **or** 2.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`get_previous_post`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) uses [**`get_adjacent_post()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) which has a bunch of filter hooks you can use but a much simpler approach would be to create your own function, something like this:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function date_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '".$post->post_date."'";
    return $where;
}

//then create your own get previous post function which will take an array of categories eg: 
// $cats = array('1','2');
function my_get_previous_post($cats){
    global $post;
    $temp = $post;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__and' => $cats
    );
    add_filter( 'posts_where','date_filter_where' );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    remove_filter( 'posts_where','date_filter_where' );
    while ($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post;
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a>';
    }
    $post = $temp;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not getting the expected results with that code. It returned the same post instead of the above, and also the loop never ends. [Here](http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-baAtZNPfKvM/Tm_nH6p_GRI/AAAAAAAAG88/3JmuMdPiWbU/out2.PNG) is the output for this code: `$cats = array('6045','6241');
my_get_previous_post($cats);`

Comment: my bad i got the filter names wrong, updated my answer.

Comment: I'm still getting the infinity loop, but it seems to work with `query_posts` instead of `WP_Query`.

Comment: Makes no sense at all.